# Drupal 7 node.tpl and page.tpl not rendering variables

Tags: drupal, theming

I'm currently working on a website with Drupal 7. I have encountered a problem when trying to build a tpl file. I have a content type named `Project(machine name: project)`, and i want a custom `node.tpl.php` and `page.tpl.php`. I am using the Zen theme, I've created the files named `node--project.tpl.php` and `page--project.tpl.php`. The thing is when i try to render a field using `$node` it doesnt show up, it stays blank, when I try to see `$node` using `dpm($node)` (from the Devel module), it doesnt show anything. What can be the problem ? It is really frustrating.

Comment: have you cleared the cache after making this change ?

Comment: $node works only in node.tpl.php

Comment: yes, i have cleared the cache many times